# program 'go' is currently not installed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: go

I ran a `sudo apt-get install golang-1.9` from my regular user account on my ubuntu 16.04 and it said everything installed correctly.  So then I typed `go version` and verified I had the right version.  Then I shut down my computer. Then I turned on my computer.  I logged in with my regular user again.  Then I typed `go version` and I get the message:

> The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing: sudo apt install golang-go

I don't want to run the `sudo apt install golang-go` because it installs the older 1.6 version.

When I try to do a `sudo apt-get install golang1.9`, the terminal says it's already installed.  So if it's alreayd installed, then why do I get a "go is currently not installed" message?

How do I get the go command to work?

Comment: take a look https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu

Comment: thanks, `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/go-1.9/bin/go /usr/bin/go` fixed things for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go installed to the `/usr/lib` directory.  So on my computer, this sym link fixed the issue

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/go-1.9/bin/go /usr/bin/go
```